# Retrieve Salesforce Object with an encrypted parameter

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, contact

i am trying to use the ampscript function DecryptSymmetric, in order to decrypt a parameter, combining with the ampscript function RetrieveSalesforceObjects from Marketing Cloud retrieving information about a contact.

This following code works:

```
 set @contact_id = RequestParameter("id")
 Set @rs1= RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Contact","Email,FirstName", "Id", "=", @Contactid)
```

but if i use this code

```
 set @contact_id = RequestParameter("id")   
 Set @clearData=DecryptSymmetric(@contact_id, 'des;mode=ecb;padding=zeros', @null, 'Password', @null, @null, @null, @null)
 Set @rs= RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Contact","Email,FirstName", "Id", "=", @clearData)
```

the system gives back this message error

> "Call to retrieve records for salesforceobject Contact failed! Error in
>   the application."

Do you have any suggestion?